# Why stop interval not work

Tags: jquery

hey guys why my stop interval not work this is my try to stop interval but fail can someone help me pleas thank you?

HTML:

```
<strong id="gg"></strong>
<button onclick="StopInterval();">Stop Interval</button>
```

JS:

```
interval();
var interval = function()
{
      var t = 10;
      setInterval(function() {
        t--;
        if (t >= 0) {
          $("#gg").html(t);
        }
        if (t === 0) {  
            clearInterval(t);
        }
      }, 1000);
}

function StopInterval() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clearInterval` is for clearing... well, *intervals*. Take your two examples:

```
var t = 10;
clearInterval(t);
```

```
var interval = function () { ... }
clearInterval(interval);
```

In your first example, you're trying to do `clearInterval()` on `t`, which is an *integer*. In the second, you're doing it on `interval`, which is a *function*.

Try this instead:

```
var t = 10;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
        t--;
        if (t >= 0) {
          $("#gg").html(t);
        }
        if (t === 0) {  
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 1000);

function StopInterval() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4uzupcmk/) of this snippet.

---

**EDIT:** Given your commented updated that you'd now like to include a start button, please see [**this JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6RhG/267/).

Comment: Thanks but with this one setInterval go to run with page load but i must run setInterval with function such as onclick() or when other function have some results and clearInterval with stop  button .

Comment: `var myVar = setInterval ...` should just be `myVar = setInterval ...` for yours to work.